# Polynomial Features Error: X has 10 features, but PolynomialFeatures is expecting 9 features as input

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, data-science, sklearn-pandas

Today i'm modeling a dataframe using PolinomialFeatures from sklearn but I keep encountering this error: `ValueError: X has 10 features, but PolynomialFeatures is expecting 9 features as input.`

Coming from the line where I generate the new data frame X_train_I

Here's my code

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(df.drop(["Faltas"],axis=1),df.Faltas,train_size = 0.8)
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
poly=PolynomialFeatures(interaction_only=True,include_bias=False).fit(X_train)
X_train_I=pd.DataFrame(poly.transform(df),columns=poly.get_feature_names(X_train.columns))
print(X_train_I.head(5))
type here
```

Any suggestions would be great! Thanks

Comment: Please provide details about datasource and some sample dataset to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should transform `X_train` and not `df`:

```
#                                   HERE --v
X_train_I = pd.DataFrame(poly.transform(X_train), columns=poly.get_feature_names(X_train.columns))
```

Or `poly.transform(df.drop(columns='Faltas'))`

Comment: This was the error! Thank you very much :)))